# Pesquisar dentro do html - sem utilizar banco de dados

Tags: html

Eu queria um campo `<input>` na minha página no qual, seu eu digitasse algo, pesquisaria se existe a palavra que eu digitei dentro dessa `section`. Não estou usando banco de dados afinal, não tem necessidade dele (os dados estão no HTML). Posso usar algum plugin, algo assim? Estou usando Bootstrap.

Segue código da página:

Itinerários | Urban

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sl-slide.css">

<script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>


<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/ico/bus.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="images/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="images/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="images/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="images/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
```

```
<!--Header-->
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>
            <a id="logo" class="pull-left" href="index.html"></a>
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse pull-right">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="index.html">Início</a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="itinerarios.html">Itinerários</a></li>
                    <li><a href="sobre-nos.html">Sobre Nós</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contato.html">Contato</a></li>
                    <li><a href="trabalhe-conosco.html">Trabalhe Conosco</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">SBE (Bilhetagem) <i class="icon-angle-down"></i></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>
                            <li><a href="blog-item.html">Estudante</a></li>
                            <li><a href="faq.html">Empresas e Instituições</a></li>
                            <li><a href="pricing.html">Idosos</a></li>
                            <li><a href="404.html">Cidadão</a></li>
                            <li><a href="typography.html">PNE / PNA</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="terms.html">FAQ</a></li>
                            <li><a href="terms.html">Informações</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="login">
                        <a data-toggle="modal" href="#loginForm"><i class="icon-lock"></i></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>        
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<!-- /header -->


<section class="title">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span6">
                <h1>Itinerários</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="span6">
                <ul class="breadcrumb pull-right">
                    <li><a href="index.html">Início</a> <span class="divider">/</span></li>
                    <li class="active">Itinerários</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- / .title -->      
<section class="itinerarios">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span4">
                          <a href="#" >002 - Formosa via Shell</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >003 - Formosa 4º Etapa</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >004 - Tesouro</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >005 - Boa Vista</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >006 - Paraíso</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >007 - Fabril via Goiás</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >008 - Fabril via IAPC</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >009 - Vila Góis João Luis</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >010 - Bairro de Lourdes</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >011 - Tropical</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >012 - Alexandrina via Presidente</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >013 - Nova Vila</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >014 - Progresso</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >015 - Vila Mariana União</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >016 - Bandeiras</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >018 - Industrial Brasil Hyundai</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >019 - São José via Calixto Abraão</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >020 - Santa Maria via Brasil Park Shopping</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >021 - Vivian Parque Calixtópolis</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >022 - Trilhos Cecrisa via Brasil</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >023 - Residencial Copacabana</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >024 - Jardins das Américas via Universitária</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >025 - Vila Esperança</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >027 - Santa Isabel via Huana</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >028 - Recanto do Sol via Universitária</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >029 - Vila Góis Circular</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >030 - Hering Depósito via Jundiaí</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >031 - Arco Verde</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >032 - Jd. Europa Novo Jundiaí</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >034 - Rodoviária</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >035 - Nações Unidas Pq. Primavera</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >036 - Guabi Porto Seco</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >037 - Frei Eustáquio</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >038 - Vila São Vicente</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >039 - Bom Clima</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >041 - Parque Pirineus via Universitária</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >042 - Santo Antônio Summerville via Flor de Liz</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >043 - Jardim Promissão via Santos Dummont</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >044 - Jandaia via Presidente</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >045 - Industrial via Jundiaí</a><br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span4">
                          <a href="#" >046 - Trilhos via Vivian Parque</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >047 - Trilhos via Jundiaí</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >048 - Campos Elíseos via JK</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >049 - Hering Depósito via Brasil</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >051 - Jaiara Trilhos via Brasil</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >053 - Residencial Morumbi / Jibran</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >054 - Facchini Industrial via Brasil</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >058 - Parque Iracema via Universitária</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >060 - Vila União via Mariana</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >061 - Senhora d'Abadia</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >062 - Vale das Antas via Res. Araguaia</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >064 - Recanto do Sol via Brasil</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >065 - Flamboyant Vila Sul</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >066 - Ibirapuera</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >067 - Residencial leblon</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >069 - Jardim Promissão via Base Áerea</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >070 - Filostro via Morada Nova</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >071 - Joanápolis</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >073 - Ipanema via Jd. Itália</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >074 - São Carlos</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >076 - Souzãnia via Interlândia</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >079 - Trilhos Recanto do Sol</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >081 - Santa Cecília</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >082 - Facchini via Brasil</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >083 - Bairro de Lourdes via JK</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >084 - Nova Capital via Santa Casa</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >085 - Jandaia Champion via Presidente</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >086 - Champion Jandaia via Presidente</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >087 - Polocentro Res. Giovani Braga</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >088 - São José via Goiás</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >089 - Roses Garden</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >090 - Branápolis via Santa Casa</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >091 - Las Palmas via Presidente</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >092 - Alexandrina via Matinha</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >093 - Recanto do Sol Facchini Trilhos</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >095 - Facchini via Jundiaí</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >096 - São Paulo Setor Sul via Fibra</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >097 - Vivian Parque Facchini Trilhos</a><br>
                          <a href="#" >098 - Lapa Fabril via Goiás</a><br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span4">
                      <a href="#" >099 - Polocentro São João</a><br>
                      <a href="#" >101 - Filostro Champion via Bairro de Lourdes</a><br>
                      <a href="#" >102 - Fabril Champion via Pedro Ludovico</a><br>
                      <a href="#" >103 - Champion Filostro via Bairro de Lourdes</a><br>
                      <a href="#" >105 - Residencial Veneza Parque Pirineus</a><br>
                      <a href="#" >106 - Filostro Champion via Tesouro</a><br>
                      <a href="#" >107 - Champion Filostro via Tesouro</a><br>
                      <a href="#" >108 - Jardim Primavera via Santo Expedito</a><br>
                      <a href="#" >109 - Jaiara Facchini Trilhos</a><br>
                      <a href="#" >110 - Trilhos Facchini Jaiara</a><br>
                      <a href="#" >111 - Jaiara Champion via Brasil</a><br>
                      <a href="#" >112 - Champion Jaiara via Brasil</a><br>
                      <a href="#" >113 - Recanto do Sol Champion</a><br>
                      <a href="#" >114 - Champion Recanto do Sol</a><br>
                      <a href="#" >115 - Trilhos via Pedro Ludovico</a><br>
                      <a href="#" >116 - Facchini Trilhos via Pedro Ludovico</a><br>
                      <a href="#" >117 - UEG Fibra via Brasil</a><br>
                      <a href="#" >118 - Vale do Sol via Residencial Araguaia</a><br>
                      <a href="#" >119 - Residencial dos Ipês via Universitária</a><br>
                      <a href="#" >120 - UEG Fibra via Jundiaí</a><br>
                      <a href="#" >121 - Parque Iracema / Jardim América</a><br>
                      <a href="#" >122 - Vivian Parque Paraíso</a><br>
                      <a href="#" >123 - Facchini Trilhos Recanto do Sol</a><br>
                      <a href="#" >124 - Champion via Pedro Ludovico</a><br>
                      <a href="#" >125 - Champion via Jundiaí</a><br>
                      <a href="#" >127 - Vivian Parque via São Vicente</a><br>
                      <a href="#" >129 - Itamarati via Tiradentes</a><br>
                      <a href="#" >131 - Champion Fabril via Pedro Ludovico</a><br>
                      <a href="#" >132 - Aldeia dos Sonhos via Guanabara</a><br>
                      <a href="#" >133 - Joanápolis via Jardim Primavera</a><br>
                      <a href="#" >134 - Residencial Bela Vista Tangará</a><br>
                      <a href="#" >135 - Jardim Primavera via Filostro</a><br>
                      <a href="#" >136 - Champion via Brasil</a><br>
                      <a href="#" >138 - Jardim Peixoto via Promissão</a><br>
                      <a href="#" >139 - Miranópolis via Aldeia dos Sonhos</a><br>
                      <a href="#" >140 - Adriana Dom Felipe via Tiradentes</a><br>
                      <a href="#" >141 - Unievangélica</a><br>
                      <a href="#" >144 - Industrial via Santa Casa</a><br>
                      <a href="#" >147 - Champion via Vivian Parque</a><br>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

```
    <!--row-fluids-->
    <div class="row-fluid">

        <!--Contact Form-->
        <div class="span3">
            <h4>ENDEREÇO</h4>
            <ul class="unstyled address">
                <li>
                    <i class="icon-home"></i><strong>Endereço:</strong>Av. Brasil Norte, 1655<br>Anápolis, GO
                </li>
                <li>
                    <i class="icon-envelope"></i>
                    <strong>E-mail: </strong> contato@urban.etc.br
                </li>
                <li>
                    <i class="icon-phone"></i>
                    <strong>Telefone:</strong> 0800 029 1900
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--End Contact Form-->

        <!--Important Links-->
        <div id="tweets" class="span3">
            <h4>NOSSA EMPRESA</h4>
            <div>
                <ul class="arrow">
                    <li><a href="sobre-nos.html">Sobre Nós</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
                    <li><a href="trabalhe-conosco.html">Trabalhe Conosco</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Informações</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>  
        </div>
        <!--Important Links-->
```

© 2015 Urban - Mobilidade Urbana de Anápolis. Todos os direitos reservados.

```
        <div class="span6">
            <ul class="social pull-right">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-facebook"></i></a></li>                  
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="span1">
            <a id="gototop" class="gototop pull-right" href="#"><i class="icon-angle-up"></i></a>
        </div>
        <!--/Goto Top-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Login
    
    
    
        
            
            
            Entrar
        
        Esqueceu sua senha?

Comment: Tem vários plugins para isso, você pode pesquisar por "autocomplete" exemplo: http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=typeahead-with-local-dataset

Comment: Uau. Gostei muito desse, mas para ele se auto completar, teria que colocar todas essas linhas e números no local do script do js certo? Poderia me indicar mais alguns?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se você sabe em qual elemento procurar você pode pesquisar o texto digitado pelo usuário comparando-o com os textos desses elementos dentro da seção, exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    /*
     Ao pressionar uma tecla no campo de busca
     OBS:Se desejar pode colocar um botão de ação e mudar para onclick neste botão
    */
 $('#buscar').on('keyup',function(){
       //pegar o valor do input e transformar em minúscula
       var texto = $('#buscar').val().toLowerCase();
           
        //seleciona todos os elementos a dentro da section
        var a = $(this).parents('section').find('a');
  $.each(a,function(){//percorre os elementos
         //texto do elemento também em letra minúscula
         var aTexto = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            //se encontrar o valor procurado no texto do elemento
         if(aTexto.indexOf(texto) > -1){
             $(this).show(); //exibe
            } else {
             $(this).hide(); //oculta
            }
      
        });
  });
});
```

```css
section.itinerarios a{display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<section class="itinerarios">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <input type="text" id="buscar" class="form-control" placeholder="Pesquisar"/>   
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <a href="#" >002 - Formosa via Shell</a>
        <a href="#" >003 - Formosa 4º Etapa</a>
        <a href="#" >004 - Tesouro</a>
        <a href="#" >005 - Boa Vista</a>
        <a href="#" >006 - Paraíso</a>
        <a href="#" >007 - Fabril via Goiás</a>
        <a href="#" >008 - Fabril via IAPC</a>
        <a href="#" >009 - Vila Góis João Luis</a>
        <a href="#" >010 - Bairro de Lourdes</a>
        <a href="#" >011 - Tropical</a>
        <a href="#" >012 - Alexandrina via Presidente</a>
        <a href="#" >013 - Nova Vila</a>
        <a href="#" >014 - Progresso</a>
        <a href="#" >015 - Vila Mariana União</a>
        <a href="#" >016 - Bandeiras</a>
        <a href="#" >018 - Industrial Brasil Hyundai</a>
        <a href="#" >019 - São José via Calixto Abraão</a>                        
      </div><!--/.span4-->       
    </div><!--/.row-->
 </div><!--/.container-->
</section><!--/.itinerarios-->
```

**Uma dica:** Tente retirar as tags `<br>` de seu código e colocar `display:block` no CSS, como no exemplo, para colocar os elementos encontrados no topo da lista.

Comment: A questão é que não consigo fazer esses scripts de .js, funcionar no meu código, como se algum outro .js estivesse interferindo.

Comment: @AdsonHenrique você verificou no console do navegador se gera algum erro? Tente depurar o código por partes, por exemplo, primeiramente veja se o script está carregando coloque um `alert` depois do `$(document).ready(function(){ alert('carregou')...`, se sim teste o `$('#buscar').on('keyup',function(){alert('keyup')...` e assim por diante.

Comment: Certo @abfurlan - Agradeço de coração. Me ajudou muito, consegui resolver o problema, e esse código de .js que você me ensinou, é exatamente o que eu quero. Finalmente está funcionando, da forma que eu gostaria que fosse. Agradeço de coração por ter tido paciência comigo.

Comment: @AdsonHenrique ok fico feliz em poder ajudar, se a resposta respondeu sua pergunta marque-a como aceita, assim outras pessoas com a mesma dúvida saberão que a resposta também serve para elas.

Answer (score 5):

tem alguns plugins para autocomplate, mas talvez o datalist do proprio HTML já lhe seja suficiente:

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("[list]");
var onListChange = function (event) {  
  var self = event.currentTarget;  
  var option = self.list.querySelector("option[value='" + self.value + "']");
  var hidden = document.getElementById(self.dataset.hidden);
  
  hidden.value = option ? option.dataset.value : null;  
  if (hidden.value) {
    var myEvent = new CustomEvent("valueSelected", { detail: hidden.value });
    self.dispatchEvent(myEvent);
  }
};

[].forEach.call(inputs, function (input, indice) {
  input.addEventListener("input", onListChange);      
});

var busca = document.getElementById("busca");
busca.addEventListener("valueSelected", function (event) {
  alert(event.detail);
});
```

```html
<label>
  Busca:
  <input id="busca" type="text" list="opcoes" data-hidden="opcao" />
  <input id="opcao" type="hidden" />
</label>
<datalist id="opcoes">
  <option data-value="#page002.html" value="Formosa via Shell"></option>
  <option data-value="#page003.html" value="Formosa 4º Etapa"></option>
  <option data-value="#page004.html" value="Tesouro"></option>
  <option data-value="#page005.html" value="Boa Vista"></option>
  <option data-value="#page006.html" value="Paraíso"></option>
  <option data-value="#page007.html" value="Fabril via Goiás"></option>
  <option data-value="#page008.html" value="Fabril via IAPC"></option>
  <option data-value="#page009.html" value="Vila Góis João Luis"></option>
  <option data-value="#page010.html" value="Bairro de Lourdes"></option>
  <option data-value="#page011.html" value="Tropical"></option>
  <option data-value="#page012.html" value="Alexandrina via Presidente"></option>
  <option data-value="#page013.html" value="Nova Vila"></option>
  <option data-value="#page014.html" value="Progresso"></option>
  <option data-value="#page015.html" value="Vila Mariana União"></option>
  <option data-value="#page016.html" value="Bandeiras"></option>
  <option data-value="#page018.html" value="Industrial Brasil Hyundai"></option>
  <option data-value="#page019.html" value="São José via Calixto Abraão"></option>
  <option data-value="#page020.html" value="Santa Maria via Brasil Park Shopping"></option>
  <option data-value="#page021.html" value="Vivian Parque Calixtópolis"></option>
  <option data-value="#page022.html" value="Trilhos Cecrisa via Brasil"></option>
  <option data-value="#page023.html" value="Residencial Copacabana"></option>
  <option data-value="#page024.html" value="Jardins das Américas via Universitária"></option>
  <option data-value="#page025.html" value="Vila Esperança"></option>
  <option data-value="#page027.html" value="Santa Isabel via Huana"></option>
  <option data-value="#page028.html" value="Recanto do Sol via Universitária"></option>
  <option data-value="#page029.html" value="Vila Góis Circular"></option>
  <option data-value="#page030.html" value="Hering Depósito via Jundiaí"></option>
  <option data-value="#page031.html" value="Arco Verde"></option>
  <option data-value="#page032.html" value="Jd. Europa Novo Jundiaí"></option>
  <option data-value="#page034.html" value="Rodoviária"></option>
  <option data-value="#page035.html" value="Nações Unidas Pq. Primavera"></option>
  <option data-value="#page036.html" value="Guabi Porto Seco"></option>
  <option data-value="#page037.html" value="Frei Eustáquio"></option>
  <option data-value="#page038.html" value="Vila São Vicente"></option>
  <option data-value="#page039.html" value="Bom Clima"></option>
  <option data-value="#page041.html" value="Parque Pirineus via Universitária"></option>
  <option data-value="#page042.html" value="Santo Antônio Summerville via Flor de Liz"></option>
  <option data-value="#page043.html" value="Jardim Promissão via Santos Dummont"></option>
  <option data-value="#page044.html" value="Jandaia via Presidente"></option>
  <option data-value="#page045.html" value="Industrial via Jundiaí"></option>
  <option data-value="#page046.html" value="Trilhos via Vivian Parque"></option>
  <option data-value="#page047.html" value="Trilhos via Jundiaí"></option>
  <option data-value="#page048.html" value="Campos Elíseos via JK"></option>
  <option data-value="#page049.html" value="Hering Depósito via Brasil"></option>
  <option data-value="#page051.html" value="Jaiara Trilhos via Brasil"></option>
  <option data-value="#page053.html" value="Residencial Morumbi / Jibran"></option>
  <option data-value="#page054.html" value="Facchini Industrial via Brasil"></option>
  <option data-value="#page058.html" value="Parque Iracema via Universitária"></option>
  <option data-value="#page060.html" value="Vila União via Mariana"></option>
  <option data-value="#page061.html" value="Senhora d'Abadia"></option>
  <option data-value="#page062.html" value="Vale das Antas via Res. Araguaia"></option>
  <option data-value="#page064.html" value="Recanto do Sol via Brasil"></option>
  <option data-value="#page065.html" value="Flamboyant Vila Sul"></option>
  <option data-value="#page066.html" value="Ibirapuera"></option>
  <option data-value="#page067.html" value="Residencial leblon"></option>
  <option data-value="#page069.html" value="Jardim Promissão via Base Áerea"></option>
  <option data-value="#page070.html" value="Filostro via Morada Nova"></option>
  <option data-value="#page071.html" value="Joanápolis"></option>
  <option data-value="#page073.html" value="Ipanema via Jd. Itália"></option>
  <option data-value="#page074.html" value="São Carlos"></option>
  <option data-value="#page076.html" value="Souzãnia via Interlândia"></option>
  <option data-value="#page079.html" value="Trilhos Recanto do Sol"></option>
  <option data-value="#page081.html" value="Santa Cecília"></option>
  <option data-value="#page082.html" value="Facchini via Brasil"></option>
  <option data-value="#page083.html" value="Bairro de Lourdes via JK"></option>
  <option data-value="#page084.html" value="Nova Capital via Santa Casa"></option>
  <option data-value="#page085.html" value="Jandaia Champion via Presidente"></option>
  <option data-value="#page086.html" value="Champion Jandaia via Presidente"></option>
  <option data-value="#page087.html" value="Polocentro Res. Giovani Braga"></option>
  <option data-value="#page088.html" value="São José via Goiás"></option>
  <option data-value="#page089.html" value="Roses Garden"></option>
  <option data-value="#page090.html" value="Branápolis via Santa Casa"></option>
  <option data-value="#page091.html" value="Las Palmas via Presidente"></option>
  <option data-value="#page092.html" value="Alexandrina via Matinha"></option>
  <option data-value="#page093.html" value="Recanto do Sol Facchini Trilhos"></option>
  <option data-value="#page095.html" value="Facchini via Jundiaí"></option>
  <option data-value="#page096.html" value="São Paulo Setor Sul via Fibra"></option>
  <option data-value="#page097.html" value="Vivian Parque Facchini Trilhos"></option>
  <option data-value="#page098.html" value="Lapa Fabril via Goiás"></option>
  <option data-value="#page099.html" value="Polocentro São João"></option>
  <option data-value="#page101.html" value="Filostro Champion via Bairro de Lourdes"></option>
  <option data-value="#page102.html" value="Fabril Champion via Pedro Ludovico"></option>
  <option data-value="#page103.html" value="Champion Filostro via Bairro de Lourdes"></option>
  <option data-value="#page105.html" value="Residencial Veneza Parque Pirineus"></option>
  <option data-value="#page106.html" value="Filostro Champion via Tesouro"></option>
  <option data-value="#page107.html" value="Champion Filostro via Tesouro"></option>
  <option data-value="#page108.html" value="Jardim Primavera via Santo Expedito"></option>
  <option data-value="#page109.html" value="Jaiara Facchini Trilhos"></option>
  <option data-value="#page110.html" value="Trilhos Facchini Jaiara"></option>
  <option data-value="#page111.html" value="Jaiara Champion via Brasil"></option>
  <option data-value="#page112.html" value="Champion Jaiara via Brasil"></option>
  <option data-value="#page113.html" value="Recanto do Sol Champion"></option>
  <option data-value="#page114.html" value="Champion Recanto do Sol"></option>
  <option data-value="#page115.html" value="Trilhos via Pedro Ludovico"></option>
  <option data-value="#page116.html" value="Facchini Trilhos via Pedro Ludovico"></option>
  <option data-value="#page117.html" value="UEG Fibra via Brasil"></option>
  <option data-value="#page118.html" value="Vale do Sol via Residencial Araguaia"></option>
  <option data-value="#page119.html" value="Residencial dos Ipês via Universitária"></option>
  <option data-value="#page120.html" value="UEG Fibra via Jundiaí"></option>
  <option data-value="#page121.html" value="Parque Iracema / Jardim América"></option>
  <option data-value="#page122.html" value="Vivian Parque Paraíso"></option>
  <option data-value="#page123.html" value="Facchini Trilhos Recanto do Sol"></option>
  <option data-value="#page124.html" value="Champion via Pedro Ludovico"></option>
  <option data-value="#page125.html" value="Champion via Jundiaí"></option>
  <option data-value="#page127.html" value="Vivian Parque via São Vicente"></option>
  <option data-value="#page129.html" value="Itamarati via Tiradentes"></option>
  <option data-value="#page131.html" value="Champion Fabril via Pedro Ludovico"></option>
  <option data-value="#page132.html" value="Aldeia dos Sonhos via Guanabara"></option>
  <option data-value="#page133.html" value="Joanápolis via Jardim Primavera"></option>
  <option data-value="#page134.html" value="Residencial Bela Vista Tangará"></option>
  <option data-value="#page135.html" value="Jardim Primavera via Filostro"></option>
  <option data-value="#page136.html" value="Champion via Brasil"></option>
  <option data-value="#page138.html" value="Jardim Peixoto via Promissão"></option>
  <option data-value="#page139.html" value="Miranópolis via Aldeia dos Sonhos"></option>
  <option data-value="#page140.html" value="Adriana Dom Felipe via Tiradentes"></option>
  <option data-value="#page141.html" value="Unievangélica"></option>
  <option data-value="#page144.html" value="Industrial via Santa Casa"></option>
  <option data-value="#page147.html" value="Champion via Vivian Parque"></option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: Certo. Ambos os plugins são excelentes, nunca imaginei que poderia ter algo assim (desculpe minha ignorância). O grande porém, é que no caso todas os itens dessa lista são referenciáveis (link). Então pensei que para o meu caso, teria que ter uma botão "pesquisar". que quando ele clicar, direciona ele pra outra aba, com o resultado do que ele pesquisou, dai ele pode clicar no conteúdo que ele pesquisou e dai ser redirecionado. Basicamente, o cara iria pesquisar "Recanto do Sol", clicaria em pesquisar, iria para outra página, lá apareceria as opções para ele, ele escolheria e seria redirecionad

Comment: você pode colocar um `data-custom` no seu `datalist`, no caso eu coloquei o seu link no `data-value`... note que ao selecionar um valor, estou dando um alert no link, neste ponto você pode fazer um redirect.

Comment: Desculpe minha ignorância, mas poderia me mostrar, como ficaria?

Comment: É porque no meu código em si, não aparece nem o alert quando seleciono uma linha. Só acontece aqui, no site, quando executo. Postei meu código completo.

Comment: vou tentar fazer algo que aproveite o seu HTML atual.

Comment: Ficarei muito agradecido TobyMosque. De coração!